# newspaper(python) get all cnn news url

Tags: python, html, python-newspaper

for example in this url (https://edition.cnn.com/search/?q=%20news&size=10&from=5540&page=555)

In html file i can find this link(html tag)

```
<div class="cnn-search__result-thumbnail">         
     <a href="https://www.cnn.com/2018/03/27/asia/north-korea-kim-jong-un-china-visit/index.html">
  <img src="./Search CNN - Videos, Pictures, and News - 
    CNN.com_files/180328104116china-xi-kim-story-body.jpg">
 </a>
```

but in this code

```
    cnn_paper = newspaper.build(url, memoize_articles=False)
     for article in cnn_paper.articles:
          print(article.url)
```

i can not find news link

https://edition.cnn.com/search/?q=%20news&size=10&from=5540&page=555
https://edition.cnn.com/search/?q=%20news&size=10&from=5550&page=556

get same link

Comment: Please be elaborate with your question. What are you exactly asking?

Comment: i want to get all news link in Specific site

Comment: https://edition.cnn.com/search/?q=%20news&size=10&from=5550&page=556 <- site is showing news list

Comment: Can you please post the value of url you are sending as a parameter in the .build() method of newspaper library.

Answer (score 1):

The search results are dynamically displayed from a JSON file from a different request:
https://search.api.cnn.io/content?q=news&size=50&from=0

size can be 50 at max.

```
res = requests.get("https://search.api.cnn.io/content?q=news&size=50&from=0")
links = [x['url'] for x in res.json()['result']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

for numb in ('1', '100'):
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://edition.cnn.com/search/?q=%20news&size=10&from=5540&page=555")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, from_encoding=resp.info().get_param('charset'))

    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        print(link['href'])
```

Or, maybe this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.dammit import EncodingDetector
import requests

resp = requests.get("https://edition.cnn.com/search/?q=%20news&size=10&from=5540&page=555")
http_encoding = resp.encoding if 'charset' in resp.headers.get('content-type', '').lower() else None
html_encoding = EncodingDetector.find_declared_encoding(resp.content, is_html=True)
encoding = html_encoding or http_encoding
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, from_encoding=encoding)

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(link)
```

Comment: in this way i can all link except news link                                                                 
  news  contain news date in url